# WPF Derived UserControl Doesn't Open in Visual Studio (but runs)

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to develop a UserControl following MVVM pattern so I created a ViewModel class that contains all the features. Then I realized all the code within the UserControl was to expose the commands, properties and events of the ViewModel, so I thought I might as well make the ViewModel the base class that derives itself from UserControl.

So I have something like this

```
<local:MediaPlayerUIViewModel x:Class="EmergenceGuardian.MediaPlayerUI.MediaPlayerUI"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmergenceGuardian.MediaPlayerUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="46" Width="800" x:Name="UI">
    <local:MediaPlayerUIViewModel.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MediaPlayerUI;component/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:TimeSpanToDoubleConverter x:Key="TimeSpanToDoubleConverter"/>
            <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </local:MediaPlayerUIViewModel.Resources>
    ...
```

Base class looks like this

```
public class MediaPlayerUIViewModel : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Now, **Visual Studio refuses to load the UserControl in the designer.** It says that the members Resources, Height and Width are not recognized or not accessible.

However, it loads in Blend and runs fine. Just Visual Studio designer doesn't like it. Any way to fix that?

**EDIT:** Sometimes taking a break and coming back later solves things. Closing Visual Studio and re-opening it fixed the problem!!

Comment: If I want to expose a UserControl usable by others, I can't expose the ViewModel directly, but I do need to expose the various properties, commands and events. The only 2 solutions I see is remapping all members I want to expose with glue code, or making the ViewModel the base. The base has no awareness of the UI controls so it still maintains a clean separation.

Comment: A UserControl should not have a view model at all. Instead it should only expose dependency properties that you can bind to properties of an externally supplied view model. This is typically passed to the DataContext of the UserControl by property value inheritance from e.g. a window where the UserControl is used.

Comment: In the case of a UserControl used only within the application. If the UserControl is meant to be used by others, then it's a completely different story. Some say that MVVM pattern doesn't apply in this case, but I got it to work that way, and it's working pretty well. Of course I'm open to hear better suggestions.

Comment: MVVM does not mean your UserControl should have its own view model. This is a common misconception , but nevertheless wrong. It should expose bindable properties like any other control. If you take a look at the WPF framework, or any third party control library, does any of the controls there have its own view model?

Comment: I got the code working, a UI for media players. I'm using this simple project as an exercise to study proper programming practices and code models. Perhaps you can take a look and provide suggestions? What I like is the code-behind contains only UI-related code and not much code. What I don't like is it contains a lot of code to switch to full-screen mode. I do think separating the UI from the logic is good practice. https://github.com/mysteryx93/MediaPlayerUI.NET/blob/master/MediaPlayerUI/MediaPlayerUI.xaml.cs

Comment: Without taking a closer look, it should easily be possible to rename MediaPlayerUIViewModel to MediaPlayerUIBase, remove the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and convert all properties to dependency properties (which have their own change notification mechanism).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173164/discussion-between-etienne-charland-and-clemens).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change this:

`<local:MediaPlayerUIViewModel x:Class="EmergenceGuardian.MediaPlayerUI.MediaPlayerUI"`

to

`<UserControl x:Class="EmergenceGuardian.MediaPlayerUI.MediaPlayerUI" ...`

the "local" identifier is declared inside of the body itself:

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmergenceGuardian.MediaPlayerUI"`

Also you can change: 
`<local:MediaPlayerUIViewModel.Resources>`
to just `<Resources>`

Your actual code of:
`public class MediaPlayerUIViewModel : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged`

can still stay the same, and everything will work.

Comment: I did change it to <UserControl.Resources> but all these syntaxes work anyway. It wasn't causing the issue.